# UIActivityView in AppDelegate using protocol and delegation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am trying to implement an `UIActivityView` in my app. It is already working, but what I need to do now is to create a method in `AppDelegate`to be used by every other class, so I don't need to repeat the code.

In my `AppDelegate`, I have the following method:

```
- (void)acionarActivityIndicator {
    NSLog(@"mETODO APPDELEGATE");
    // Show the activity indicator
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    view.frame = self.window.bounds;
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2);
    [view addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.window addSubview:view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

That method is declared in a `@protocol`.h file.

```
@protocol ActivityIndicatorProtocol <NSObject>

@required

- (void)acionarActivityIndicator;

@end
```

Now, on `buttonClick`or whatever, I need to place this view over the active VC. For so, I'm setting `AppDelegate`the `delegate`of my VC.

I have this on `viewDidLoad`of VC:

```
ITAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[ITAppDelegate alloc] init];
    self.delegate = appDelegate;
    NSLog(@"DELEGATE %@", self.delegate);
```

This is correctly assigning delegate. Delegate `@property`is declared in my VC .h like this:

`@property(nonatomic, assign)id delegate;`

Now, also in `viewDidLoad`, for testing purposes, I try to show the `UIActivityIndicatorView`by calling method in `AppDelegate`.

`[self.delegate acionarActivityIndicator];`

This is not working, and I don't know why. I can place activityIndicators using other strategies, but I really want to learn how to properly do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
ITAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ITAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

insted of

```
ITAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[ITAppDelegate alloc] init];
```